# Allow exception when inserting record with or check and short circuit first?

Tags: entity-framework

For an HttpPost operation where the object being inserted has an alternate key, what would be considered the best option for handling a database conflict when inserting?

Should I check if the entity exists first and return an error code that there is a conflict

```
    if (ReportingContext.Reports.Any(r => r.ReportId == report.ReportId))
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
    }
```

Should I simply allow the operation to go through, allowing a successful addition into the database if there is no conflict, or an exception to be thrown if there is a conflict?

What is worse? The two calls to the database, one to check if the entity exists and the second to insert the new entity... or the overhead of creating a new entity in memory and assigning all the properties, only to have it exception out because there was a conflict? Burden on database vs needless burden on server?

Comment: Even if you checked there still might be a race where someone else inserts an entity after you check if it exists and before you save entities.

Comment: It all depends on other functional/non-functional requirements, preferences, traditions,... which is a long-winded way to say: opinion based.

Comment: So probably not a good fit question then...